# Using a scatter plot and world map image to display meteor impacts on a map, Aspect ratio problems

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I'm attempting to plot meteorite impacts using python in the pycharm IDE on a equirectangular map projection(loaded as a standard image) this is "animated" through time incrementing to show impacts in 50 year periods from 1500 to present.

To do this I am using a tuple list of lat and lon coordinates (from a NASA csv file) that have been normalized (represented between 0 - 1) to plot points on a scatter plot this is then overlapped with the map image.

Brief code explanation:
In the first part the normalize_lat_lon pulls from a data processing file I have written that normalizes the latitude and longitude.

Impacts is a list of tuples that are Year, Lat, Lon.
img is the world map image which resolution is 2048 x 1025
the 1.998*a is my attempt at rectifying the ratio problem I have.
As the resolution is almost 2:1 by multiplying the x values by 1.998 (2048/1025)
It in theory should allow me to plot accordingly.

This is part of the main code:

```
lat_lon = [data.normalise_lat_lon(b, c) fpr a, b, c in impacts]
x, y = [1.998*a for a, b in lat_lon], [b for a, b in lat_lon]

plt.scatter(x, y, s=200, color='red')
plt.imshow(img)
```

My problem is scaling the scatter plot to line up with the world map image.
using the above fix multiplying the 1.998*a seems to have all the scatter plot points stuck in the top left hand corner as shown below.

[Meteorite Impacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/045FZ.png)
MCV: Simplified version of the code without looping through other time periods or needing to normalise the lat an lon from the nase file

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plot.title("Meteorite Impacts 1990 - 2000")

impacts = [(1994, 0.5, 0.3),(1991, 0.4, 0.3),(1998, 0.1, 0.1),(1992, 0.8, 
0.8)]
lat_lon = [(b, c) for a, b, c in impacts]
x, y = [1.9*a for a, b in lat_lon], [b for a, b in lat_lon]
plt.imread("Equirectangular-projection.jpg")
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I could put a https to a git of the project for others to clone/fork, not sure if I'm allowed to do that.

Comment: To my understanding you can't do that like this. The axis you have are not Lat-Lon, you need to use a proper geographic library to do this. check out basemap: https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: FWIW,  NASA equirectangular maps have the correct aspect ratio. I suggest editing your background image: either just crop that extra row of pixels, or scale x2, crop a row at the top and bottom and scale back down.

Comment: a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) would help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two reasons it turns out.

1 - The imshow() function plots pixel by pixel so I had to multiply the x an y by there respective axis resolutions namely (2048 x 1025)

2 - I also had latitude and longitude confuzzled, turns out long is x and lat is y